# Not able to authenticate office 365 via IMAP auth-2.0 : NO AUTHENTICATE failed

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365, imap

I am trying to get all the emails sent to a email address into my node.js application. For this, I am using IMAP. plain password suddenly stopped working 3 days ago. I came to know that we need to setup Auth-2.0 to make it work.

Firstly, I did app registration in [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/).

I followed the instructions given on [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth)

I am able to get access_token via postman request.following is the Node.js Code snippet from postman for the request:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/292........f9/oauth2/v2.0/token',
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie': 'fpc=AoRIZjYQr2JOsS57j2DVG4jEeor3AQAAAJtTjtsOAAAA; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd'
  },
  form: {
    'client_id': '124.....1',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'response_mode': 'query\n',
    'scope': 'https://outlook.office365.com/.default',
    'client_secret': 'j1....F'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Following is the Code that I am using to Connect microsoft office 365 servers through IMAP :

```
var Imap = require('node-imap'),  
  inspect = require('util').inspect;  
  var buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
const mailId = 'support@example.com';  
const token =  
  'ey.......LA';  
//const auth2 = btoa("user="+mailId+"\x01auth=Bearer "+token+"\x01\x01");
const auth2 = buffer.from(("user="+mailId+"\x01auth=Bearer "+token+"\x01\x01")).toString('base64');  
  
  console.log(`auth2=>`,auth2);

//new Imap({xoauth2:btoa, ... })

var imap = new Imap({  
  xoauth2: auth2,  
  host: 'outlook.office365.com',  
  port: 993,  
  tls: true,  
  debug: console.log,  
  authTimeout: 25000,  
  connTimeout: 30000,  
  tlsOptions: {  
    rejectUnauthorized: false,  
    servername: 'outlook.office365.com'  
  }  
});  
  
function openInbox(cb) {  
  imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);  
}  
  
imap.once('ready', function () {  
  openInbox(function (err, box) {  
    if (err) throw err;  
    var f = imap.seq.fetch('1:3', {  
      bodies: 'HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)',  
      struct: true  
    });  
    f.on('message', function (msg, seqno) {  
      console.log('Message #%d', seqno);  
      var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';  
      msg.on('body', function (stream, info) {  
        var buffer = '';  
        stream.on('data', function (chunk) {  
          buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');  
        });  
        stream.once('end', function () {  
          console.log(  
            prefix + 'Parsed header: %s',  
            inspect(Imap.parseHeader(buffer))  
          );  
        });  
      });  
      msg.once('attributes', function (attrs) {  
        console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));  
      });  
      msg.once('end', function () {  
        console.log(prefix + 'Finished');  
      });  
    });  
    f.once('error', function (err) {  
      console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);  
    });  
    f.once('end', function () {  
      console.log('Done fetching all messages!');  
      imap.end();  
    });  
  });  
});  
  
imap.once('error', function (err) {  
  console.log(err);  
});  
  
imap.once('end', function () {  
  console.log('Connection ended');  
});  
  
imap.connect();
```

Following is the Error that I am getting after running above code at node.js :

```
Error: AUTHENTICATE failed.
    at Connection
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitReadable_ (node:internal/streams/readable:590:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  type: 'no',
  textCode: undefined,
  source: 'authentication'
}
```

I have added app permissions as per docs (Screenshot attached).

[image: App Registration]

As per my understanding, I am missing something on Azure Active Directory.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added `API permissions` same as you like below:

[image]

Now, I ran similar code as you and got **access token** successfully like below:

```js
const request = require('request');

const clientId = '07865bdd-7e5a-414e-94a8-xxxxxxxx';
const clientSecret = 'wwe8Q~Isr6IFcv3uxxxxxxxxxf4';
const tenantId = '3f5c7a77-062d-426c-8582-xxxxxxxxxxx';
const scope = 'https://outlook.office365.com/.default';

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  form: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    scope: scope,
  },
};

request(options, (error, response, body) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }

  const accessToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
  console.log(`Access token: ${accessToken}`);
});
```

**Response:**

[image]

But when I used this token to fetch emails via IMAP, I'm not getting any response.

Alternatively, I tried using **MS Graph API** by granting **`Mail.Read`** permission for my application like this:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** by changing scope to Microsoft Graph like this:

```js
const request = require('request');

const clientId = '07865bdd-7e5a-414e-94a8-xxxxxxxx';
const clientSecret = 'wwe8Q~Isr6IFcv3uxxxxxxxxxf4';
const tenantId = '3f5c7a77-062d-426c-8582-xxxxxxxxxxx';
const scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  form: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    scope: scope,
  },
};

request(options, (error, response, body) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }

  const accessToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
  console.log(`Access token: ${accessToken}`);
});
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token in running below Graph query via Postman, I got all emails received from specific user in **response** successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq 'xxxsridevim@microsoft.com'
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Call Microsoft Graph in a Node.js console app - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-console)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to solve my issue. I tried using Microsoft graph APIs and it worked like charm. Even, I used subscriptions as well so that Microsoft automatically informs my application about new email. Thanks