Problem with connecting to Outlook via IMAP using OAuth2 authentication
We are building a solution where we connect to email mailboxes via IMAP, fetch and store some relevant emails, so that later we can display them in the web UI. Later on we plan to add support for replying to the relevant emails directly from web UI.
We have implemented OAuth2 for authenticating an IMAP connection to Outlook mailboxes via OAuth2 identity platform using authorization code flow. It was working during the initial testing using personal Outlook mailboxes (the ones from outlook.live.com) back in ~January/February 2024, but it doesn't work anymore. We also need it to work with enterprise Outlook mailboxes, but we didn't test if it worked back in ~January/February 2024.
Nowadays it fails when trying to authenticate IMAP connection to Outlook mailbox, even the personal one. The authorization code flow itself works fine and we are able to get access tokens without any problems, but these access tokens not working as expected.
Error we are getting:
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.

Some technical details about our solution:

It's written in Java and we are using Java Mail library to establish IMAP connection, fetch and store some relevant emails
We are using SASL XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism for IMAP
We have an application registered in Microsoft Entra ID with the following settings:

Supported account types: Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)
Configured permissions:

Microsoft Graph (delegated)

IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
SMTP.Send
User.Read
offline_access







During the OAuth2 authorization code flow we request IMAP.AccessAsUser.All, SMTP.Send, User.Read, offline_access scopes (without any prefixes), and use https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize as authorization endpoint.
If we try to change scopes to be https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All, SMTP.Send, User.Read, offline_access (as per documentation here), it expectedly fails during authorization code flow with invalid_scope error.
We have read documentation from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth, but it asks to use deprecated scopes that we cannot configure for our application anymore (they are not on the list), and later part of the document talks about using client credentials grant flow, which is not what we need (we want to access mailboxes on behalf of the user).
We would like to get help how to make it work. Thanks in advance!
EDIT:
We were able to make it work using the idea described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48584417/25413714.
What we are doing now is the following:

Acquire access & refresh tokens using Microsoft Graph scopes (IMAP.AccessAsUser.All, SMTP.Send, User.Read, offline_access)
Immediately after that request a new access token using refresh token from the previous step, but this time with Outlook scopes (https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send)

This new access token works and allows an IMAP connection to Outlook. But this "solution" does not look like something intended and we are not sure how long it would continue to work.

Alternatively, make use of Microsoft Graph API by adding Mail.Send permission of Delegated type. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75577881/not-able-to-authenticate-office-365-via-imap-auth-2-0-no-authenticate-failed/75605034#75605034

Hi @Sridevi, we have tried using Microsoft Graph API with Mail.Read & Mail.Send permissions, and it works fine, but we really would prefer to stick with IMAP, so that we can use the same code for not only Outlook, but other email providers as well.
